Booting QNX image on Raspberry Pi 4 get stuck in rainbow screen
I am following a tutorial (https://gitlab.com/qnx/quick-start-images/raspberry-pi-qnx-8.0-quick-start-image/-/wikis/Getting-Started) to flash QNX image onto Raspberry Pi 4. I copied the QNX image (com.qnx.qnx800.quickstart.rpi4) using Raspberry Pi Imager to the SD card without any issue. When I insert the SD card into the Raspberry Pi, I only see the rainbow screen without seeing the main QNX welcome page.
I am using a 32GB SanDisk SD card and a Raspberry Pi 4. I just need some help to troubleshoot the issue.

I found the issue. I was connecting the micro SD card into the Raspberry Pi using micro SD card USB adapter. After inserting the micro SD card into the Raspberry Pi’s card slot, I was able to boot the QNX image successfully.
